# Does Linux have a problem with CRLF newlines?

Tags: linux, git

I've been arguing about this with my team. In development, we use Windows (CRLF) and on the server we use Linux (LF).

Is there a problem if Linux sees a file with CRLF newlines? Should Git handle such a case via the `.gitattributes` file?

Comment: The vast majority of tools will get an extra character at the end of each line when reading those files. Whether that's a problem or not is up to you.

Comment: git (with an appropriate .gitattributes config) will auto-convert line endings, so no problem.   Most other unix programs (especially those which work on entire lines of text) will not work or, worse, will not work *properly* but give no indication that they actually failed in subtle and annoying ways.  perl is pretty good at handling files with  either LF or CRLF if you code carefully, but most other tools and languages (grep, tr, sed, cut, sort, join, paste, sh/bash, awk, python, php, C and all the other usual suspects) are not.   Text files on unix end in LF only. Unix tools expect that.

Comment: Also note that a unix text file **must** end every line with an LF.  A common mistake is to NOT end the last line of a file with an LF - many tools/languages will cope just fine with a file that doesn't have an LF on the last line but technically that file is not a text file (it's something that is very much **like** a text file but isn't), and some programs will choke on it.

Comment: @cas forgive me I'm a pedant.  An empty (zero byte) file is a correct text file under POSIX / linux. / unix.

Comment: Yes you should configure `git` to handle end-of-lines automatically in source files, your colleagues are totally right.

Comment: @PhilipCouling does an empty file have a last line of text? or any line of text?  No. So there are no lines that need to end in LF.

Comment: I would not even bother with conversion. Your IDE should be perfectly capable of handling Linux endings in source code files. If the target is Linux, set the line ending to \n in your IDE, problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly the linux Kernel itself does not know or care about line endings when you upload files to your server.  Though as [muru notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665427/does-linux-have-a-problem-with-crlf-newlines/665477?noredirect=1#comment1252240_665477) CRLF will screw up a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

However there is a convention on in Linux that all lines in text files end in a single LF. Many tools will read the CR and treat it as any other **regular character** (a,b,c,...).  This comes from the [POSIX definition of a text file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#3.403).

This *can* cause problems in some languages such as shell scripts (sh, bash, zsh, ksh, ...).  If you are lucky the script will fail on a syntax error caused by a spurious extra argument.  However in bad cases this can creep into the content of files and file names.

This is mostly a problem for tools and languages which are only designed to run under linux / unix.  Many platform independent languages and tools auto adapt.  So you are unlikely to see a problem an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), or code editor.

---

So to attempt to end your argument with your colleagues, no linux does not have a problem with CRLF line endings.  **However** some tools and languages can choke or do strange things if you leave them in.

If you are writing code to be run on Linux / Unix platforms then it's generally easier to configure git to strip any CR characters for you leaving you with LF line endings.

Comment: I think the kernel does care about line endings in one *extremely* user-visible place: shebang lines.

Comment: @muru I knew if I said it someone would find an exception. Are there any others you can think of?

Comment: Some of the knobs exposed as files, maybe? I think writing to some sysctl files can error out if you use CRLF.

Comment: @muru Yeah I was wondering about `/proc` `/sys`.

Comment: Yes, just checked: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio` - OK,  `printf '%s\r\n' 1  > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio` *not* OK; `echo performance | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` OK,  `printf '%s\r\n' performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` *also* OK. Strangely inconsistent.

Comment: @muru I think "inconsistent" here means "undefined".  I've made a correction and scoped the statement to uploading files (rather than controlling things in /proc)

Comment: @muru you can "fix" the shebang problem with `binfmt_misc`. And while at it, also make it handle the "fake BOM" (an invisible character prepended by windows text editors to any utf-8 file) which is also breaking shebangs.

Answer (score 3):

In general, POSIX defines a text file as a file where each line ends in a LF.  As such, most POSIX utilities will see a CRLF as a line with a normal line ending with a CR before the end, which is treated as a normal character.

Whether that is acceptable depends on your needs.  For example, `wc` will probably not care very much about the CR when counting words, whereas you may find that using `cut` or `awk` to select certain fields may end up outputting a CR that you didn't expect.  As others have noted, most POSIX-compatible shells (even on Windows) don't appreciate the CR and will simply refuse to work with a syntax error

Most text editors regardless of platform can handle both CRLF and LF endings, and some can also handle the legacy MacOS (that is, MacOS 9 and before) CR line endings.  Thus, which line endings you should use depend mostly on personal preference, the platform you're on, and the tools you're working with.

If you're using Git, the best thing to do is to tell Git that certain files are text files (that is, they should have their line endings converted).  That will cause Git to store files internally with LF endings, and then convert them on checkout as desired.  You can do this by adding something like this to your `.gitattributes` file in the repository:

```
*.c text
*.h text
*.sh text eol=lf
*.ps1 text eol=crlf
*.jpg -text
```

This specifies that `.c` and `.h` files are text and can be checked out with line endings according to the user's configured settings, and will be written into the repository with LF endings.  For `.sh` files, both the repository and working tree will have LF endings, and for `.ps1` files, the repository will have LF endings and the working tree will always have CRLF endings, regardless of platform.  `.jpg` files won't have any line-ending conversion done at all.

If you don't want to specify every kind of file, you can simply write this:

```
* text=auto
```

and Git will try to do the right thing automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Linux applications and applications libraries **mostly** handle all types of newlines including `CRLF` (MS-DOS, Windows) or `LF` (Unix, Linux) seamlessly. You don't need to change or specify anything. Old **classic** MacOS (**not** modern MacOS X) uses `CR` and such files will not be handled properly (everything will be a single line).

There are situations where you may have troubles with `CR`s but you can solve them on a case by case basis.

```bsh
$ wc -l /tmp/test-*
 2 /tmp/test-dos.txt
 0 /tmp/test-mac.txt
 2 /tmp/test-unix.txt
 4 total
```

Tools to remove CRs are `dos2unix` and e.g.:

```bsh
tr -d '\r' < input > output
```

or `sed`

```bsh
sed -i 's/\r$//g' file
```

Comment: _"applications and applications libraries seamlessly handle all types of newlines"_ -- yeah, well, tell that to all the questions here about how a script from windows doesn't even start (because of a CR in the `#!` line makes the kernel look for the wrong file), or throws a weird error about an unexpected keyword (because of a CR after some keyword makes it unrecognizable), or prints stuff weirdly (because of a CR in the output moving the cursor).

Comment: I think that is misleading to the OP and to others with an incomplete understanding. Linux will indeed process multi-line text files by recognising `LF  '\n' octal 12 dec 10 hex 0A as a line separator. The difference is that Windows will also strip any preceding CR, but Linux will treat it as data to be passed to the reader, often with obscure and elusive consequences.

Comment: @ilkkachu nice catch :-) Never seen such files though and who would want to create scripts for Unix in Windows? :-)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov really? Linux isn't the most popular desktop environment but is very popular as a server, embedded device, mobile device... most developers will not be on a Linux desktop.

Comment: I'm surrounded by web application developers (HTML, JS, CSS, shell, ruby, python) and all of them (over ten people) use Ubuntu. Maybe I'm lucky.